# Передача JavaScript переменной в PHP

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

Помогите правильно сделать отсылку переменной из JavaScript в файл PHP

```
function spin(id) {
    $('#ro').removeAttr('class');

    setTimeout( 
        function() { 
            $('.spinpage').fadeOut('fast');
        }, 
        0
    );

    $.post('/ro.php', { id : id }, function(data) {
        var rol = data;
    ...
}
```

Как правильно передать переменную `rol` в файл `qer.php` в виде пост запроса асинхронного? Я сам пытался сделать но у меня вообще отказывал скрипт.

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример по клику,например. В data подставляете свои данные.

```
$('#send').on('click', function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'post.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {'username': 'Jack', 'password': 'secret'},
    success: function (s) {
      console.log(s);
    },
    error: function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Вот как передать переменную rol под именем test например

Comment: @TheAs110z data: {'test': rol},

Answer (score 0):

```
// Первый запрос
$.post('/ro.php', { id : id }, function(data){
    // Когда первый запрос вернул данные
    var rol = data;
    // Отправить их по второму адресу
    $.post('/ger.php', { test : rol });
});
```